# Adding items to Bootstrap navbar across multiple templates

Tags: django, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to add items from multiple templates to one navbar with bootstrap? Specifically, I have an HTML template that's extended by almost all of the rest of my pages, and it includes a bootstrap navbar. I want to add additional menu options to this same navbar from the individual templates (eg: on a scheduling page, I want to add a link to create a new event) Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set a block in your base template

```
{% block navbar %}
```

inside your navbar div and then in the other templates you can add whichever extra elements you want in that block and they will appear in the nav bar.